# import class in django (nginx) while getting 502 error

Tags: python, django, nginx, uwsgi

I wrote a python class, named DataExportToJson, which is used to read a file and export them into JSON formate. Then I embedded this class in another class, called ProcessFromData, like the following way:

```
import DataExportToJson  **#Example(1)**
class ProcessFromData：
    def processing(self, fileName):
        (doing something...)
        DataExportToJson.export_json(fileName)
    return True
```

The above code runs well if its directly called from my console. Then this ProcessFromData class is embedded inside a view file in Django server. (I am using django 1.5.5 and nginx 1.1.19) That is, in a views.py I wrote this:

```
from thirdparty.ProcessFromData import ProcessFromData
def BookApp(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        inStance = ProcessFromData()
        inStance.processing(fileName)
```

By using the above code, I got a "502 Bad Gateway " error. In the log, I saw:

```
[error] 21443#0: *4 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 192.168.157.1, server: BookAppcollect, upstream: "uwsgi://unix:///tmp/uwsgi.sock:",
```

After several trials, I mistakenly change ProcessFromData class by re-importing the DataExportToJson class:

```
class ProcessFromData：   **#Example(2)**
    def processing(self, fileName):
        (doing something...)
        import DataExportToJson           **#difference here**
        DataExportToJson.export_json(fileName)
    return True
```

Then everything goes fine. Now I am confused. 
My questions are:

1. what is the difference between #Example(1) and #Example(2)
2. is the problem coming from the memory limit? how does the "502 Bad Gateway " error happen?

Comment: Have you tried running this code on the built in development server? Import #1 is failing perhaps due to name conflict or circular dependency and when imported within the function (#2) it succeeds. Importing within the function is only deferring the loading in this instance which appears to resolve the issue. It's still imported only once though.

Comment: @AndrewS There is not a name conflict or dependency issue. What I did was to use example1 while importing another file with small amount of data. That works:(... So there should not be anything wrong with the code grammar. I guess something wrong with the memory or processing time limit?